# What's the error in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
    "UPDATE realizaIm SET fechaHoraEntrega='"+fechaHoraEntrega+"', fechaEntrega='"+fechaEntrega+"' WHERE cvePaciente='"+cvePaciente+"' AND WHERE cveAnalisis='"+cveAnalisis+"';";
```

I'm getting an error here, it says it's near `WHERE cveAnalisis='"+cveAnalisis+"';";`

I just can't find it, please help

Comment: you are using 2 WHERE clause. remove second where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `WHERE` from:

```
WHERE cvePaciente='"+cvePaciente+"' AND WHERE cveAnalisis='"+cveAnalisis+"'
```

so it should be like this:

```
WHERE cvePaciente='"+cvePaciente+"' AND cveAnalisis='"+cveAnalisis+"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "WHERE" clause only once.

```
"UPDATE realizaIm SET fechaHoraEntrega='"+fechaHoraEntrega+"', fechaEntrega='"+fechaEntrega+"' WHERE cvePaciente='"+cvePaciente+"' AND cveAnalisis='"+cveAnalisis+"';";
```

The right syntax to use [WHERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) clause is `

"...WHERE condition1 **AND** condition2 **OR** conditions3..."